# Element with border-radius inside element with border-radius is not consistent

Tags: html, css, border, border-radius

I have a layout that most likely can't be changed. I need to use border-radius on an element inside another element with border-radius. **The purpose is to fill the white gap**. The issue is that the corners of the child elements are overflowing, but I can't use `overlow:hidden` in this project, which is why I am trying with border-radius.

Here is a snippet to show my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/5fgtL4so/5/

The issue is that inner border-radius of 30px does not have the same curve as outer border-radius. I don't want to hardcode this since it has to be responsive. I also tried to play around with width and margins as you can see on the snippet, but it does not seem to be the right way since I still have a small margin of error.

Any idea how to tackle this problem?

```css
.parent {
  border: 3px solid tomato;
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.child {
  border: 3px solid tomato;
  padding:10px;
  border-bottom: none;
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* bellow solution is not perfect. There is still tiny white space around innter corners, it's a bit more visible on my project */
  /*
  margin-left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whats wrong with margin-left: -3px; width: calc(100% + 6px); margin-top: -3px; height: 103px; ?

Comment: @VXp I did not think of margin-top even though I was pretty close since I used margin-left. But I thought somehow there must be a better approach since it sounded quite hacky, not sure.

Comment: Exactly, you were pretty close, that's why it's a bit funny. :) Another approach would be to reduce the child's border-radius to 23px (30px - combined border-width + 1).

Comment: Aha indeed. I don't know how you did that calculation but 30px parent and 23px child does not have the same border curve I just checked so I don't think it's correct. Around 27px sounds right, but again, I don't know a logic way to get this result.

Comment: Combined meaning 3px + 3px, prob. I should use summed up. To me 23px looks just fine, but yeah depends on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inset box-shadow` instead of `border`.

```css
.parent {
  /*border: 3px solid tomato;*/
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0 3px tomato;
}

.child {
  border: 3px solid tomato;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: none;
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, your solution is works if you add `margin-top: -3px` also.

```css
.parent {
  border: 3px solid tomato;
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.child {
  border: 3px solid tomato;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: none;
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: -3px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then the height needs to be 103px.

Comment: How did I not think of that! It is indeed a solution in my case (fixed height was for the snippet but it's actally based on content height so not a big matter). I also found the margin fix with top as well but it seems hacky.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is a bit late for this question, by setting the parent's `overflow: hidden` and removing the radius altogether from the child you can achieve what you need.

```css
.parent {
  border: 3px solid tomato;
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  border: 3px solid tomato;
  padding:10px;
  border-bottom: none;
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```